# How can I print these numbers in correspoding location with array?

Tags: java, arrays, file, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class PracticeFinal {
   public static void main (String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
       Scanner input = new Scanner (new File("altitude.txt"));
       int[] x = new int [400];
       int[] y = new int [400];
       float[] altitude = new float [400];
       x[0] = 0;
       y[0] = 0;
       altitude[0] = 0;
       int i = 0;
       System.out.println("x\ty\taltitude");
      while (input.hasNextFloat()) {
          int line = input.nextInt();
          x[i]=line;
          int line2=input.nextInt();
          y[i]=line2;
          float line3 = input.nextFloat();
          altitude[i]=line3;
          System.out.println(x[i]+"\t" + y[i]+"\t"+ altitude[i]+"\t");
          i+=1; }
           printMax(altitude,x,y);
           printMin(altitude,x,y);
           printAverage(altitude);
           printContour(altitude,x,y);
        }   
   public static void printMax(float []altitude, int []x, int []y) {
       float max=altitude[0];
       int ind=0;
       for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
       {
           if (altitude[i]>max)
           {
               max = altitude[i];
               ind=i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The maximum altitude is "+"("+x[ind]+","+y[ind]+","+max+")");
    }
    public static void printMin(float []altitude, int []x, int []y){
        float min=altitude[0];
        int ind=0;
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            if (altitude[i] < min)
            {
                min = altitude[i];
                ind=i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The minimum altitude is "+"("+x[ind]+","+y[ind]+","+min+")");
   }
   public static void printAverage(float []altitude){
       float total = 0;
       for(int i=0;i<100;i++) 
       {
           total += altitude[i];
        }
        float avg = total / 100;
        System.out.printf("The aveage altitude of the region is " + "%.2f", avg);
        System.out.println();
   }
   public static void printContour(float []altitude, int[]x, int[]y){
       for (int i=0;i<100;i++) {
       System.out.print (altitude[i] + " ");    


}
}
}
```

I need help with the last part of this program there is an x and y chart with altitudes ex, 0,0 = 109.1 1,0= 200
So for the last method i need to print out the altitude in its corresponding location starting from 1,1 to 2,1 to 3,1 and so on 
Dont know what to do next after the for loop
This is the file im reading first number is x second is y and third is the altitude.

```
1   1   101.0 
2   2   97.2 
3   3   112.3 
4   4   114.2 
5   5   100.2 
6   6   97.5 
7   7   97.8 
8   8   81.3 
9   9   105.4 
10  10  108.7 
3   1   107.8 
3   2   115.4 
3   4   118.3 
3   5   120.3 
3   6   122.3 
3   7   90.3 
3   8   81.7 
3   9   87.4 
3   10  113.2 
1   2   102.3 
1   3   104.5 
1   4   109.8 
1   5   99.8 
1   6   88.9 
1   7   89.3 
1   8   100.1 
1   9   110.8 
1   10  98.3 
2   1   98.8 
2   3   80.5 
2   4   85.1 
2   5   83.2 
2   6   92.3 
2   7   94.3 
2   8   199.3 
2   9   104.3 
2   10  105.2 
4   1   120.5 
4   2   87.3 
4   3   82.3 
5   1   83.2 
5   2   84.5 
5   3   96.9 
5   4   86.7 
4   5   115.3 
4   6   101.3 
4   7   102.6 
4   8   106.9 
4   9   109.8 
4   10  93.4 
6   7   93.2 
6   8   92.4 
6   9   80.9 
6   10  81.2 
5   6   102.3 
5   7   101.1 
5   8   106.7 
5   9   105.3 
5   10  88.9 
6   1   80.8 
6   2   81.3 
6   3   84.5 
6   4   90.8 
6   5   99.8 
8   1   98.6 
8   2   101.1 
8   3   103.5 
8   4   104.6 
8   5   105.8 
8   6   80.9 
8   7   80.1 
7   1   98.3 
7   2   96.4 
7   3   95.1 
7   4   83.4 
7   5   95.1 
7   6   96.3 
7   8   99.9 
7   9   100.0 
7   10  102.3 
10  3   99.9 
10  4   98.3 
10  5   91.3 
10  6   94.3 
10  7   95.3 
10  8   103.2 
8   9   90.2 
8   10  91.3 
9   1   93.2 
9   2   81.5 
9   3   91.0 
9   4   95.3 
9   5   122.3 
9   6   119.8 
9   7   118.7 
9   8   117.3 
9   10  107.8 
10  1   108.8 
10  2   109.9 
10  9   104.2
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit Andrew Li! first time using this sorry.

Comment: I think a simple sort will do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void printContour(float []altitude, int[]x, int[]y){
   for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++) {
            if (x[i] <  x[a]) {
                int temp_for_x = x[i];
                x[i] = x[a];
                x[a] = temp_for_x;
                int temp_for_y = y[i];
                y[i] = y[a];
                y[a] = temp_for_y;
                float temp_for_alt = altitude[i];
                altitude[i] = altitude[a];
                altitude[a] = temp_for_alt;
            }
            if(y[i] < y[a]){
                int temp_for_x = x[i];
                x[i] = x[a];
                x[a] = temp_for_x;
                int temp_for_y = y[i];
                y[i] = y[a];
                y[a] = temp_for_y;
                float temp_for_alt = altitude[i];
                altitude[i] = altitude[a];
                altitude[a] = temp_for_alt;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int incr=0;incr<100;incr++) {
         System.out.print(x[incr]+ "   " + y[incr] + "   " + altitude[incr]+ "   ");
         if(incr%10 == 9)
            System.out.println();

   }



}
}
```

There are better sorting algorithms you can use [Here](http://www.cs.csubak.edu/~msarr/visualizations/Algorithms.html)

Comment: Thanks alot! Ill check those algorithms out. Do you possible know how i can print out the altitude results 10x10 instead of all on one line?

Comment: yeah you can I edited the answer to display 10x10 if you think my answer is good (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: awesome thanks I voted for your answer! appreciate you!